# Laravel, using pivot table in relations

Tags: laravel, relation

Laravel 5.3, I have this two models:

User, with this relations:

```
public function newFunctions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\NewFunctions', 'user_newfunctions');
}
```

NewFunctions:

```
public static function getAllFunctions() {
    $functions = DB::table('new_functions as nf')
    ->select('nf.*')
    ->get();
    return $functions;
}

public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_newfunctions', 'new_function_id', 'user_id');
}
```

(that `getAllFunctions` was there before I receive this code... don't talk about it, there are a lot of another Controllers using that method... I don't know if its the version or not, but why the hell the old programmer didn't use `all()` instead )

Then, in my controller I do this:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);

foreach ($user->newFunctions as $key => $function) {
    //dd($function);
    $user_new_functions[] = [$function->id, 69];
}
dd($user_new_functions);
```

With `dd($function);` I get this:

```
NewFunctions {#961 ▼
  #table: "new_functions"
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:7 [▶]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "pivot" => Pivot {#962 ▼
      #parent: User {#770 ▶}
      #foreignKey: "user_id"
      #otherKey: "new_functions_id"
      #guarded: []
      #connection: null
      #table: "user_newfunctions"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: false
      #attributes: array:2 [▼
        "user_id" => 814
        "new_functions_id" => 1
      ]
      #original: array:2 [▶]
      #relations: []
```

And with `dd($user_new_functions);` I get:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 69
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 3
    1 => 69
  ]
]
```

What I need is, instead `69` I need to pass the value of `function_count` that is in the pivot table `user_newfunctions`

That table is this one:

```
user_id | new_functions_id | function_count
-------------------------------------------
    814 |           1      |   5
    814 |           3      |   7
```

So that I will have in `dd($user_new_functions);`  this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 5
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => 3
    1 => 7
  ]
]
```

That array is my goal. Please, any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `->withPivot()` method on the relationship:

`User.php`:

```
public function newFunctions(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\NewFunctions', 'user_newfunctions')->withPivot(['function_count']);
}
```

`NewFunctions.php`:

```
public function users(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_newfunctions', 'new_function_id', 'user_id')->withPivot(['function_count']);
}
```

Now, when querying the relationship, a `->pivot` property, containing all the columns from the `->withPivot()` method will be available. You can replace the `69` with the following:

```
$user = User::with(['newFunctions'])->findOrFail($id);
foreach ($user->newFunctions as $key => $function) {
  $user_new_functions[] = [$function->id, $function->pivot->function_count];
}
dd($user_new_functions);
```

Note: added `with(['newFunctions'])` for eager loading (potential performance increase, but not required)

The documentation describes how to retrieve intermediate table columns slightly below the "Many to Many" relationship information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: You are my hero by 2nd time I guess, because your name looks purple. Great!! Thanks. I will test it now, seems all fine.